# How to map values from table to correct row using SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following data:

```
supplier   count
120         50
121          45
129         
151          0.5
```

I have a table as follows

```
Catergory  Discription   number_of_suppliers
   A          count NULL                                  
   B          0<=count<40                              
   C          40.1<count
```

I want to map it as follows:

```
Catergory  Discription   number of suppliers
   A          count NULL       1                     //129
   B          0<=count<40           1                    //151
   C          40.1<count           2                    //120,121
```

I know it should be something like:

```
Update categories set number_of_suppliers = sum(case when count>0 and count<40 then 1 else 0 end ) where Category=A
from suppliers
```

But this means I need to run this query 3 times.. One per row.
Is there a way to do it with a single update query?

Answer (score 1):

With your existing data structure, this is hard.  Instead, fix your second table, so it looks like

```
Category      Description     min_suppliers   max_suppliers
   A          count NULL      0               0                              
   B          0<count<40      1               40                          
   C          40.1<count      41              NULL
```

Then you can do the update as:

```
update categories
    set category = (select t2.category
                    from t2
                    where categories.num_suppliers >= t2.min_suppliers and
                          (categories.num_suppliers <= t2.max_suppliers or t2.max_suppliers is null)
                   );
```

Comment: Hi, I thought of that but this it problematic. 0 is not the same as null. it should be: null to null, 0 to 40, 40.1 to unlimited